# Automatically run script after connected to PPTP server

Tags: windows-xp, pptp

I'm using PPTP connection to connect to my office

And I want to add a static route after connected to PPTP server. My problem is my IP on this connection is automatic

Is there any way to run a script to manually add a route to route table when connected to PPTP server?

I'm using Windows XP SP3

Comment: No one has any clue?

Comment: Still no? :((((

Answer (score 1):

If you're still using DHCP to hand out the IP address to the client on the other subnet, you can also pass down non-persistent routes that survives the life of the connection.

Its under 'SCOPE OPTIONS' in the MS world of DHCP, but assume it similar in all implementations.

I've seen this done, and it seems to work fine.